# how to change java swing look and feel without application restart?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

is there a specific way to change the look and feel of a swing application without needing to restart the application every time the LAF got changed by the user?

im looking for a solution where one can select the LAF from a configuration dialog and it changes directly on apply without having to fall back to telling the user to restart the application.

currently i remember the selected LAF in a properties file and set it on startup before any window has been opened.

Comment: Does this not work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655929/lookandfeel-not-changing-in-ubuntu/2656085#2656085

Comment: @tim_yates Actually sometimes it doesn't. Listeners in particular will be fired in a different order, which shouldn't matter but often does. Also I wouldn't have total faith in PL&F uninstalls (notably if `UIResource` isn't used (as it can't with some classes and primitives), then how can the PL&F accurately detect whether the application code has an interest in a component property?).

Comment: @Tom But it might work if it's not too complex an application, and it's the only hope of a working solution other than going for the full restart, which the OP wants to avoid...

Comment: @tim_yates It might well work, but I wouldn't want to rely on the next update leaving egg on my face. If it's a well written program(!), it shouldn't be too difficult to clear the UI, change the PL&F and recreate the UI without *too much* changing.

Comment: @tim_yates also if custom colors and fonts are set, then these values should be reset in `updateUI()` method. But in general it should work. You can change L&F in IntelliJ IDEA without restarting and I wouldn't say it's a small app.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html):

You first need to set the new look and feel by calling `UIManager.setLookAndFeel`:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
```

Then, in order to make existing componentes reflect the new look and feel, call the `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI` method on each top-level container (dialogs, frames..). You might also wish to resize each top-level container to adapt to changes in the size of its contained components:

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);  // update components
frame.pack();                                 // adapt container size if required
```